# In laravel 6, take values from JS and pass them to controller and save it to database?

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel-6

my question is about I am currently have some data that I bring from epayco. The data arrives correctly but in js, I need this same data to be able to use it in php to save it in the database when these are displayed when the window is loaded. can anybody help me?

This is the code so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Respuesta de la Transacción</title>
  </head>
<body> 

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8 pt-5 pb-5">
        <h2 class="text-center">Respuesta de la Transacción </h2>
        <hr>
        <!--Table-->
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Id usuario</td>
                <td id="id_usuario"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Id promocion</td>
                <td id="id_promocion"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Referencia</td>
                <td id="referencia"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="bold">Fecha</td>
                <td id="fecha" class=""></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Respuesta</td>
                <td id="respuesta"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Motivo</td>
                <td id="motivo"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="bold">Banco</td>
                <td class="" id="banco">
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="bold">Recibo</td>
                <td id="recibo"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="bold">Total</td>
                <td class="" id="total">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--/Table-->
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-block mb-5" href="/" role="button">Regresar a la pagina de inicio de Vitur</a>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <img src="https://369969691f476073508a-60bf0867add971908d4f26a64519c2aa.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/btns/epayco/pagos_procesados_por_epayco_260px.png" class="img-fluid"> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <img src="https://369969691f476073508a-60bf0867add971908d4f26a64519c2aa.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/btns/epayco/credibancologo.png"
          height="40px" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--jQuery-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    function getQueryParam(param) {
      location.search.substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .some(function(item) { // returns first occurence and stops
          return item.split("=")[0] == param && (param = item.split("=")[1])
        })
      return param
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //llave publica del comercio
      //Referencia de payco que viene por url
      var ref_payco = getQueryParam('ref_payco');
      //Url Rest Metodo get, se pasa la llave y la ref_payco como paremetro
      var urlapp = "https://secure.epayco.co/validation/v1/reference/" + ref_payco;
      $.get(urlapp, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
          if (response.data.x_cod_response == 1) {
            //Codigo personalizado
            alert("Transaccion Aprobada");
            console.log('transacción aceptada');
          }
          //Transaccion Rechazada
          if (response.data.x_cod_response == 2) {
            console.log('transacción rechazada');
          }
          //Transaccion Pendiente
          if (response.data.x_cod_response == 3) {
            console.log('transacción pendiente');
          }
          //Transaccion Fallida
          if (response.data.x_cod_response == 4) {
            console.log('transacción fallida');
          }
          $('#id_usuario').html(response.data.x_extra1);
          $('#id_promocion').html(response.data.x_extra2);
          $('#fecha').html(response.data.x_transaction_date);
          $('#respuesta').html(response.data.x_response);
          $('#referencia').text(response.data.x_id_invoice);
          $('#motivo').text(response.data.x_response_reason_text);
          $('#recibo').text(response.data.x_transaction_id);
          $('#banco').text(response.data.x_bank_name);
          $('#autorizacion').text(response.data.x_approval_code);
          $('#total').text(response.data.x_amount + ' ' + response.data.x_currency_code);
        } else {
          alert("Error consultando la información");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!--php-->
  @php/*
    $buy= new App\Buy;
    $buy->user_id = $_REQUEST['id_usuario'];
    $buy->promo_id = $_REQUEST['id_promocion'];
    $buy->save();
  @endphp
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an endpoint in your laravel application and do an ajax request after getting the data in epayco

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      //llave publica del comercio
      //Referencia de payco que viene por url
      var ref_payco = getQueryParam('ref_payco');
      //Url Rest Metodo get, se pasa la llave y la ref_payco como paremetro
      var urlapp = "https://secure.epayco.co/validation/v1/reference/" + ref_payco;
$.get(urlapp, function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
        $.post( "your/endpoint", response.data );
    }
});
/////
///
//
```